# PHP - in_array problems

Tags: php

I wrote the following, but its saying that its the 'wrong datatype'.

Could someone tell me where im going wrong.

```
$newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE left_id='$authId'");
$catid = mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);

if(in_array("99", $catId)){
    // A Director
} else {
    // A Researcher
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: For variable names PHP does impose case sensitivity, if only function names acted in the same manner...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assigning the row to `$catid` and later using `$catId`. Notice the capital "I". You also need to make sure `$catId` is an array because `mysql_fetch_array` will return `FALSE` if there are no rows.

Comment: +1.  @Chris, just another `crazy` thing about PHP... variables **are** case-sensitive, but function **are not**... Man this language pisses me off sometimes.